# Is it possible to extract a certain part of a string field and cast it to some other type?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have a `file` input in logstash, which reads from `/var/log/syslog`. The log message goes into `message` field. I didn't think about extracting some parts of the message beforehand, but now I would like to find all entries with the `message` field that have a word `WORD` in them and extract a number from that string, and I would like to feed that number to Kibana to build a line chart based on it.

More concretely: messages look like this:

```
{
  //... timestamp, id etc
  "message" : "User used WORD approximately 10 times"
  //
}
```

I would like to have:

```
{
  // timestamp, ...
  "message" : 10
}
```

Is it possible without some really blunt force? The worst thing I can imagine is to re-feed all the messages through the new logstash input which will structure the messages, but that looks like a really bad approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not too far along, adding a new pattern to logstash and re-feeding the logs is the easiest solution and leaves you ready to parse new logs as they arrive.

If you really need to re-grok existing records, check out the [elasticsearch](http://logstash.net/docs/latest/inputs/elasticsearch){} input in logstash, which can query your old records and re-process them.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply! I'm actually not 'too far along', since I'm actually in the process of finding a software witch suits my needs best and this is one of the most probable use-cases: I will not have the knowledge of what to extract from inputs beforehand, but I definitely will need to to it frequently. So there will definitely be a time when I'll be 'to far' and re-importing will seem like a hardly feasible task. I understand I'm asking too much, but it still would be nice to have the option though.